# Google Data Analysis Cert - RStudio the Penguins Scatterplot is not being created?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recreate course material from video and instructions. The topic is R and RStudio. I believe I have executed according to instructor, but scatter plot is not being created.

Here is code:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


data(penguins)

view(penguins)
view(penguins_raw)

ggplot(data=penguins, aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g))+geom_point(aes(color=species))
```

I'm expecting a plot of the penguins analysis to appear, but there are no plots available, even after I've run the code.

Comment: In RStudio, go to the "View" menu and choose "Show Plots" to make sure you can see the plot pane.

Comment: There is no data object named 'penguins' in the tidyverse set of packages.

Comment: @IRTFM there appears to be one in the `palmerpenguins` package. Should be a dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't be reproducible because you forgot to load the `palmerpenguins` package, which is where the `penguins` data comes from. This stripped-down version of your code worked fine for me (I omitted the `install.packages` calls, because you don't need to call that every time you run the code).

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)

data(penguins)

ggplot(data=penguins, aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=species))
```

[image]

My guess is that your Plots window isn't open, as suggested by MrFlick.

Comment: I was so excited that my code worked and my plot appeared, that I quickly responded and didn't thank you directly. So, Thank you C. Murtaugh!